# How to evaluate an array of boolean values and logical operators

Tags: ruby

I have an array of boolean values `true` or `false` separated by strings that express a logical operator `||` or `&&`, for example:

```
[true, "||", false, "&&", true]
```

The array size is not fixed. I want to evaluate the first three elements `[true, "||", false]`, and evaluate the result plus the remaining art of the array.

I am thinking of using:

```
array.each_slice(3).to_a.reduce
```

But I am not sure what to be passed in the `reduce` block. Need some direction here.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "evaluate the first three elements ... and evaluate the result plus the remaining art ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code**

```
def evaluate(arr)
  pairs = arr.drop(1).each_slice(2)
  pairs.reduce(arr.first) { |rv, (op, bool)| op == '&&' ? rv && bool : rv || bool }
end
```

**Examples**

```
evaluate [true, '&&', false, '||', true]   #=> true
evaluate [false, '||', true, '&&', false]  #=> false
```

**Explanation**

Suppose

```
arr = [true, '&&', false, '||', true]
```

Then

```
a = arr.drop(1)         #=> ["&&", false, "||", true]
pairs = a.each_slice(2) #=> #<Enumerator: ["&&", false, "||", true]:each_slice(2)>
```

We can see what elements the enumerator `pairs` will send to the block by converting it to an array.

```
pairs.to_a              #=> [["&&", false], ["||", true]]
```

Continuing (`rv` is short for *return value*), we generate the first element of `pairs`, pass it to the block and assign values to the block variables `op` and `bool`.

```
rv = arr.first          #=> true
op, bool = pairs.next   #=> ["&&", false]
op                      #=> "&&"
bool                    #=> false
```

We now perform the block calculation. As

```
op == '&&'              #=> true
```

the block computes and returns the following, which is the new value of the *memo*, `rv`:

```
rv && bool              #=> true && false => false
```

We now generate the second and last element of `pairs`, pass it to the block, assign values to the block variables (recall `rv` now equals `false`) and perform the block calculation.

```
op, bool = pairs.next   #=> ["||", true]
op                      #=> "||"
bool                    #=> true

op == '&&'              #=> false
rv || bool              #=> false || true #=> true
```

The method therefore returns `true`.

**Use [Kernel#eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) instead**

If we trust the values in the array we could simply write

```
eval [true, '&&', false, '||', true].join  #=> true
eval [false, '||', true, '&&', false].join #=> false
```

The use of `eval` would allow us to add `"("`, `")" and`"!"` to the array, greatly increasing the range of boolean expressions that could be evaluated (easily).

Comment: I think when using `eval` you can use `arr.join` i.e. without the `' '` character argument.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. This is what I was looking for. I accepted your answer.
@SagarPandya Thank you for the suggestion.